# I can't log into magento

Tags: magento, logging

I can't log into Magento,

I installed GTSPEED extension. I logged out from admin and now I can't log in, but it doesn't show any kind of error.

How could I solve it? My site is running and I need to operate. Thank You!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9075665/445330

Answer (score 0):

Before installing modules like this, it's imperative that you shut off caching (and if you use it, the compiler) and only reenable after the module has properly installed itself.

After-the-fact recovery says that you will need to clear the cache (manually by deleting all the mage--? folders in var/cache) so all the old Magento code gets flushed so Magento can properly re-read all the config files and properly integrate the module into its running system and then remove all active sessions by deleting files in var/session. Once this is done, you will have to log into the admin panel and back out about two or three times so it starts loading the menus and config setups.

Answer (score 0):

just check weather you comment this line or not

```
app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Session\Abstract\Varien.php
```

just comment this line if you not comment it find following line and comment it

```
call_user_func_array('session_set_cookie_params', $cookieParams);
```

and then check weather it's work or not