# Magento 1.8.1.0 can't login redirect without error on VPS (no local machine)

Tags: magento, cookies, vps

When I login on Magento, it redirects me to the login screen with the url:
http://www.notitieboekjes.nl/index.php/everlake/index/index/key/5cc09b2a09c7081ba3806585fce1347a/

I do not get an error message of any kind.

I've found quite some posts about this, but all are about a Local Server.
I have a clean magento (1.8.1.0) install on a VPS.

Tried everything from this post (which is about a VPS, but solutions are aimed at a local):
[Can't login to Magento admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075539/cant-login-to-magento-admin)

&

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/how_to_fix_login_for_admin_on_local_install#dokuwiki__top

all to no afail.

Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

A special note: After the magento installation I had to set the Temp Directory Manually.

As said tried all options, magento isn't installed on a local machine. So I'm lost.

All help is very much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have reinstalled magento using the Downloader.

Now the problem doesn't occur anymore. Don't know why, but I'm happy.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure you have all required PHP extensions to run Magento on your VPS:

- php5-mcrypt
- php5-gd
- php5-curl
- php5-mysql

Second, I think you're getting the login page all the time even with correct credentials. Try logging in using Google Chrome in Incognito Mode (CTRL+SHIFT+N). The reasoning here is that sometimes there are stray PHP session ID's stored on your browser that doesn't invalidate correctly. I noticed this as well with 1.8.1.0 up on non-SSL admins.

A permanent fix if the above works for you is to just get SSL and use it for your backend as well.

Comment: I have all required PHP extensions installed.

Comment: I have all required PHP extensions installed. Checked it with the check php file from magento. The server meets all the requirements. in Incognito mode I also get redirected back to the admin login page without an error message.

Comment: Clearing the browser cache solved the problem for me.

Comment: Yes, that's why you go incognito mode (for the most part)!