# magento admin not login in any browser

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.9

I am facing problem in magento admin. when i am trying to login in admin panel it give

http://localhost/myproject/index.php/admin/index/index/key/e8d39e2cf8686363a43e0524be944100/

I have tried some solution which are posted before . 
but my problem is still.

I have tried the following solution

### /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php

// session cookie params
       /* $cookieParams = array(
            'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
            'path'     => $cookie->getPath(),
            'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
            'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
            'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
        ); */

Please give me any solution for the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075539/cant-login-to-magento-admin

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on a website. One of the solution to avoid the problem is to use private navigation.

Like opening a New private window in Firefox.

This is not a permanent solution but it's fast.

Hope this can help you.