# Magento Log in issue.. front end and admin

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I recently migrated my magento website over to a new server.

The transfer went pretty seamless apart from the fact that I can't log in to the front end or admin page with the correct details.

I have tried logging in with the incorrect details to see if I could get a message saying that it was incorrect but just as it is with the correct details, both login pages loop back when the details are entered.

I have updated the core_config_data values for the base_url and all the rest. I also tried commenting out some of the code which functions the cookies in varien and still had no luck

I just can't seem to figure this one out. ny help would muchly be appreciated :)

Regards
Luke

Comment: First Check did you follow all this steps - https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/magento_move.htm     and this - http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/22120/how-to-move-magento-shop-to-another-server also this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075539/cant-login-to-magento-admin

Comment: Edit: I now have an error message when putting in the wrong username and password in the admin login but still have nothing on the front end.

Comment: go to forgot password

Comment: try different browser

Answer (score 0):

Delete everything inside var folder
update admin password

```
UPDATE `admin_user` SET `password` = MD5('NEWPASSWORD') WHERE `username` = 'ADMINUSERNAME';
```

Comment: Cache files of privious server/localhost may be the reason. Do as i mentioned

Comment: Give that a go, it just seems to hang and not do anything

Comment: update password through query UPDATE `admin_user` SET `password` = MD5('NEWPASSWORD') WHERE `username` = 'ADMINUSERNAME';

Comment: Once again, tried it and nothing. I'm starting to believe that the cookies aren't getting sorted but I can't figure out where to start!